# extend jenkins image to install maven

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins, dockerfile, docker-container

I'm using the `jenkins/jenkins:lts` image at the moment. It runs fine and does everything I want to expect one thing. I want it to run Maven goals in the build steps. The problem is that there is not maven installed in the jenkins container environment.

So I want to extend the mentioned image to run an `apt-get install maven`.

My solution:

```
FROM "jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
RUN /bin/bash -c "apt-get install maven"
```

Will this be enough? I assume that all RUN and ENTRYPOINT steps of the jenkins image will run by itself and I do not need to re-execute them in my Dockerfile right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to update package cache before install, and don't miss `-y` for `apt-get install`.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y maven
```

Comment: Worked! executing `docker-compose up`  with my new image yields `ERROR: pull access denied for jenkins/jenkins-maven, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'` - did I miss something?

Comment: show me please `docker build` command arguments for jenkins-maven image

Comment: `docker build -t jenkins-maven .`

Comment: Probably in `docker-compose.yml` image has name `jenkins/jenkins-maven`. But you built image `jenkins-maven`. Names must be the same.

Comment: I ran the command `bash -c "apt-get update && install -y maven"` in docker-compose and I got the error `E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)`. I tried with sudo as well but `bash: sudo: command not found`. Any ideas how can I run this?

Comment: @AlexPavlov, take a look at my post below.  It is more detailed.  I was having  a similar issue.

Answer (score 12):

According to the documentation, this would be in your dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
# if we want to install via apt
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y maven
# drop back to the regular jenkins user - good practice
USER jenkins
```

Assuming your docker file is in your current directory this is how you would build the image and install in your local docker repo

```
docker build -t jenkins-maven .
```

For more information

https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker

After installing maven this way, the mvn version will probably be older than what you need. When I ran this, it was Apache Maven 3.3.9

Comment: How do you know that USER jenkins is the right one? Is that somewhere defined in the base image?

Comment: @dokaspar, it is defined in base image.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the simplest way to install maven into docker:

1. Connect to docker with root privilages

   sudo docker exec -u root -t -i [container-id] bash
2. update and install maven

   apt-get update & apt-get install

That's it.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at hand. It is possible to create a image from a dockerfile with desired tools included.

Answer (score 2):

Works file for me

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y maven
```